# SvelteKit SPA: Redirect to login page if user not logged in with original path as a query parameter

Tags: authentication, sveltekit

Let's consider the following scenario.

I have a multi-tenant Sveltekit SPA app (backend is ASP.NET). When a user invites another user to his/her tenant, an email is sent to the invited user. When the invited user clicks a link in the email, the SPA app loads, and checks if the user is logged in. If not, then the original navigation (let say "/user/acceptInvitation") is *canceled*, and the invited user is redirected to login page, with the original path as a query parameter ("/user/login?returnUrl=/user/acceptInvitation").

I've tried `beforeNavigate` in root **+layout.svelte**, but it looks like `beforeNavigate` doesn't fire when the app first loaded (maybe because it handles client-side navigation only, and when the SPA app first loaded it's server-rendered).

I also want the above logic work in another scenario: If user reloads the app by full browser page refresh. The app should request logged-in user info from the server, and if there is any issue, it should redirect to login page.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you'd want to implement on the client side.

Assuming logged-in state is tracked by the existence of a session cookie on the machine of the user being invited, you would want to use server side middleware for the invitation route with the following logic:

- if the request carries a valid session cookie, user is logged in and process the invitation as requested
- otherwise redirect to login with the original request as a `returnUrl` parameter

Obviously your login implementation should also perform redirection to `returnUrl` after a successful login, or a default redirection to a page of your choosing if that parameter is not present.

Because this is handled on the server side, this will also function in your full browser refresh scenario.

Comment: Thank you! I'm actually doing invitation process on server-side; client-side page serves as an useful intermediary between the email link and server, by converting get request to post request, by pointing to api endpoint, and showing messages etc. I can probably go with your suggestion and achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial I came up with the following code in root `+layout.svelte`:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
    import http from "utilities/http";
    import User from "./User";
    import { currentUser, selectTenant } from "./appModel";
    ...

    let initialized = false;

    const url = $page.url;
    if (/* logged-in user required for the url */)
        http.get("/api/user/info")
        .then(async (res) => {
            if (res.ok) {
                currentUser.set(User.create(await res.json()));
                selectTenant("last");
            }
            else {
                const returnUrl = `${url.pathname}${url.search}`;

                // Await goto, otherwise 'returnlUrl' component
                // (or root page) may start mounting! 
                if (returnUrl !== "/") {
                    await goto(`/user/login?returnUrl=${returnUrl}`);
                }
                else {
                    await goto("/user/login");
                }
            }
            initialized = true;
        });
    }
    else {
        initialized = true;
    }

    ...

</script>

{#if initialized}
{#if $currentUser}
    <Navbar ... />
    <StatusBar ... />
    <slot />
{:else}
     <StatusBar ... />
     <slot />
{/if}
{/if}
```